# GTK3 gsettings usage

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gtk3, dconf, gsettings

*As background: Electronics engineer, follow suckless philosophy (where posible), no knowledge about X and and any kind of toolkits (GTK or Qt), using arch linux, cannot stand GNOME.*

It bothers me that gtk3 package has `dconf` and `gsettings` dependence. I cannot find a compeling explanation of what `gsettings` is used for (other than manual pages and other internet bits), what are *schemas*, and what it has to do with GNOME DE.

Mainly I am asking silly questions:

1. What is the practical usage of `gsettings` and what ties it to GNOME
   DE?
2. What separates *gtk3 rc* files from *gsettings*?
3. Any ways to avoid, or should I try to avoid `gsettings`, any
   alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

(*as I understand this*):

**dconf** is database system which keeps settings (*GVariants*) in database files and it is on the bottom layer.

**dconf schemas** are the files which contain structure of these database files.

**gsettings** is an API and a toolkit to store and retrieve this settings from and to database.

---

### Long answer

(as explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf)):

> **dconf** is a *low-level* configuration system and settings management tool. Its main purpose is to provide a back end to **GSettings** on platforms that don't already have configuration storage systems. It depends on **GLib**. It is part of **GNOME 3** and is a replacement for **GConf**.

---

> **dconf database**:
> One *dconf database* consists of a single file in binary format, i.e. it is not a text-file. The format is defined as **gvdb** (*GVariant Database file*). It is a simple database file format that stores a mapping from strings to **GVariant** values in a way that is extremely efficient for lookups.

---

> **GVariant**:
> *GVariant* is a strongly typed value datatype. *GVariant* is a variant datatype; it can contain one or more values along with information about the type of the values.
> A *GVariant* may contain simple types, like integers, or boolean values; or complex types, like an array of two strings, or a dictionary of key value pairs. A *GVariant* is also immutable: once it's been created, neither its type nor its content can be modified further. *GVariant* is useful whenever data needs to be serialized, for example when sending method parameters in DBus, or when saving settings using *GSettings*.
> *GVariant* is part of *GLib*.

---

> **GSettings**:
> The *GSettings* class provides a **high-level API** for application for storing and retrieving their own settings.
> The utility program `/usr/bin/gsettings` is contained in `libglib2.0-bin`.
> *GSettings* is part of **GIO** which is part of *GLib* (`libglib2.0-0`).